# I see/saw my baby crying OR my baby cry?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm quite confused how to use "I see (noun) (verb/ing)" in these situations:

1. My baby's crying now:

> 1a. I see my baby crying.
>
> 1b. I see my baby cry.

(Does the 2nd option mean that the baby will cry again?)

2. My baby cried in the maternity ward:

> 2a. I saw my baby crying.
>
> 2b. I saw my baby cry.

Which option is correct in each of these situations?

Comment: It would be useful to know what you're confused about in more detail.

Comment: Yes, *I see/saw/will see my baby crying* are grammatical.

Comment: I'm not sure, what is correct for 1st and what for 2nd figure see is present and saw is past, OK, but, if baby stop crying, but will cry again, what should be correct

Comment: @pazzo, question is about cry vs crying ( I see now, wrong topic tittle make me unclear )

Comment: Yes, if the baby is crying *now*, you say *I see my baby crying (now)*. It doesn't matter if the baby will cry again or not.

Comment: What about past

Comment: Another interesting thing - I see my baby *cry*, **why not** *cries?*

Comment: For the past, you can say either 2a or 2b.

Answer (score -1):

Your a-sentences imply that you saw the baby crying for a certain moment, while the b-sentences imply that you witnessed the crying from the moment it started and until it ended.

Because of that, sentence 1b seems a bit weird. *See* means that you are witnessing the crying at that moment, so you cannot use *cry* since the crying has not finished yet.

Comment: 1b can be used, but it means something different than 1a: "When she's unhappy, I see my baby cry." It means that seeing your baby cry is something that has happened, and will likely happen again, but it is not happening now. It's like "I am drinking coffee" versus "I drink coffee". In other words, the sentence is okay, but it doesn't mean "my baby's crying now".